# SQL retrieve data from two table based on the ID(Key) of the first table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I imagine this has been done many time before but I can't for the life of me figure it out and I am tired of trying work arounds.

I have two tables.
One is an Object having ObjectID(key), Name, Type, Location
Two is ObjectStatus having  StatusID(key),ObjectID,Status,DateChanged,UserWhoChangedStatus

What I want to do is return all Objects and the ObjectStatus that was entered last

Table 1 Object

```
ObjectID      Name          Type      Location
   1         Blue Ball      Ball       ToyBox
   2         Red Ball       Ball       ToyBox
```

Table 2  (ObjectStatus)

```
StatusID    ObjectID    Status    DateChanged    UserWhoChangedStatus
   1          2         Broken    2012-01-25       56481
   2          2         Fixed     2012-01-30       98526
   3          1         Bouncy    2012-01-05       85245
   4          1         Sticky    2012-02-10       56481
```

I would want to get returned

```
ObjectID Name      Type Location StatusID Status DateChanged UserWhoChangedStatus
   1     Blue Ball Ball ToyBox       4    Sticky 2012-02-10  56481
   2     RedBall   Ball ToyBox       2    Fixed  2012-01-30  98526
```

Which is all Objects and the ObjectStatus that was last entered

Comment: It would really help to know the DBMS you're using. MySql? MS Sql Server? Oracle? PostGre?

Comment: Sorry I am using MS SQl Server 2008

Comment: I don't think it's relevant because the solutions all seem to derive the right results, but it seems that you've mixed up the `ObjectID` in your expected results. 1 never had a status of fixed and 2 never had a status of sticky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't say the DBMS I will assume Ms Sql Server.

```
SELECT
   O.*,
   S.*
FROM
   dbo.Object O
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM dbo.ObjectStatus S
      WHERE O.ObjectID = S.ObjectID
      ORDER BY DateChanged DESC
   ) S
```

Comment: I am impressed. Works like a charm right out of the box.  Thank you very much I have been fighting with this for days.  I think I understand the syntax but I am going to play with it for a bit.

Comment: @K'Leg If you have a huge number of objects with only a few statuses, then using a Row_Number() solution may perform better. The opposite would be fewer objects with a huge number of statuses each. It is possible I have this backwards (gosh, I always seem to forget this).

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide an alternate solution so future readers can compare performance and pick the appropriate method in their case.

```
;WITH LastChange AS
(
  SELECT 
    ObjectID, Status, DateChanged, UserWhoChangedStatus,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ObjectID ORDER BY DateChanged DESC)
    FROM dbo.ObjectStatus
)
SELECT 
  o.ObjectID, o.Name, o.Type, o.Location,
  l.StatusID, l.Status, l.DateChanged, l.UserWhoChangedStatus
FROM dbo.Object AS o
LEFT OUTER JOIN LastChange AS l
ON o.ObjectID = l.ObjectID
AND l.rn = 1;
```

You can change the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `INNER JOIN` if you somehow know that the status table will always have at least one row for every `ObjectID`, or if you don't want to return objects that don't have a row in status.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of way to do this but I like the the following way because it seems most intuitive -- it uses a CTE and left joins which makes it simpler if the query gets more complicated:

```
WITH maxDate AS
(
    SELECT objectID, MAX(DateChanged) AS maxDate
    FROM ObjectStatus
    GROUP BY objectID
)
SELECT O.*, OS.*
FROM Object O
LEFT JOIN maxDate ON maxDate.objectID = O.ObjectID
LEFT JOIN ObjectStatus ON OS.ObjectID = O.ObjectID 
                       AND OS.DateChanged = maxDate.maxDate
```

Comment: I like this less because you have to access the ObjectStatus table twice. YMMV.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I agree that your example is probably the most performant here.  My goal was to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: This also has the flaw that it assumes maxDate to be unique per object. That may not be true. The problem with this query, then (in my mind) is someone seeing it who hasn't been given this caveat, and wastes time trying to use it (or worse, uses it without realizing for some time the duplication problem).